# Hand animation supported by OVRHandPrefab in Unity (Oculus Quest 2)

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, virtual-reality

I am new to Unity and trying to get basic hands working in terms of being able to see the hands and having them move in accordance with my own hands (preferably using controller, which I know has limited control over what it can detect hands are doing).

I configured OVRHandPrefab as shown in [this article](https://arvrjourney.com/vr-hand-tracking-with-oculus-quest-and-oculus-link-35568eb3d6f4), but I do not see the hands. I have tried using with my (physical) hands only as well, but I don't see the hands. I tried disabling hand-tracking support, but that didn't help either.

I've tried all the options in "Hand Tracking Support" in OVRCameraRig
and am using the default values for the two OVRHandPrefab objects except for changing one of them to match the right hand (since left hand seems to be default).

I also tried using the OVRCustomHandPrefab_L and ..._R, but while I do see the hands they don't animate at all in accordance with me pressing buttons or triggers. I'm not sure if these prefabs are supposed to animate out of the box though.

If anyone can suggest any troubleshooting suggestions or any steps where I can get basic animated hand models working, I'd appreciate it.

I'm using Unity 2020.3.18f1.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OVRCustomHandPrefab_L and ..._R and click "automap bones" button under OVR Custom Skeleton for each one.